# Spring JmsTemplate's Daemon threads that stay alive after stopping tomcat application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, ibm-mq, jmstemplate

I am sending a message to IBM WebSphere MQ(the mq jar version is 7.0.1.9 and javax.jms is 1.1) using a Spring JmsTemplate class from my web application.

The connectionFactory i am using is MQQueueConnectionFactory.

The following **daemon threads** are created on executing send() on JmsTempalte and on instantiating MQQueueConnectionFactory.

**PROBLEM**

I am getting a message on tomcat command line showing these three threads as memory leaks when i stop the web application in the tomcat admin page.  The daemon threads are

**FROM JCONSOLE**

**THREAD 1**

Name: JMSCCThreadPoolMaster
State: WAITING on java.lang.Object@9f6e3e9
Total blocked: 3  Total waited: 4

Stack trace: 
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:651)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:621)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:887)

**THREAD 2**

Name: JMSCCThreadPoolWorker-2
State: WAITING on com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteReconnectThread$ReconnectMutex@3d3c3e45
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 1

Stack trace: 
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteReconnectThread.bestHconn(RemoteReconnectThread.java:672)
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteReconnectThread.run(RemoteReconnectThread.java:129)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:298)
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1220)

**THREAD 3** (**Dies after a min**)

***THIS ONE is created on instantiation of MQQueueConnectionFactory***

Name: WebSphere MQ Trace Monitor
State: TIMED_WAITING
Total blocked: 0  Total waited: 5

Stack trace: 
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
com.ibm.mq.commonservices.internal.monitor.TraceMonitor.run(TraceMonitor.java:134)

How to make sure these daemon threads die.

Comment: Hello Santosh, did you ever find any solution to this. Thanks

Comment: Hi yes,  i answered below http://stackoverflow.com/a/24594788/2386297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Spring context was not closing properly and the JMS Connection factory was being managed by my spring container therefore it caused the leak.

Comment: did you try to use transactional context source?

Comment: Hi yes i tired transaction connection factory for JMS,  had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that problem is within WMQ client jars and not within spring. Remove client jars from application and provide them at higher classloader level like coping them within tomcat/lib folder. This will not solve the problem, but work around it, as all applications will share common base and no leak will happen on application restart.